# Easy T-transformation in R went wrong

Tags: r, cycle

everyone! I'm not an expert in R, but I have some experience. However, now I have no idea, what to do.

I have dataframe, where some columns should be transformed into T-scale (T-scores with mean = 50 and sd=10). The formula for that is 50+10*(x-M)/SD. Where m is mean of original column and SD is a standard deviation of original column.

I have a vector containing names of necessary columns. And I wrote cycle to transform my data. But something went wrong, and after the transformation my data looks like columns of gradually decreasing values. Please, help!

My code:

```
mmpi <- c("L_SMOL", "F_SMOL", "K_SMOL", "Hs1SMOL", "D2SMOL", "Hy3SMOL", "Pd4SMOL", "Pa6SMOL", "Pt7SMOL",
      "Se8SMOL","Ma9SMOL")

for (i in 1:11){
data.main[j,mmpi[i]] <- 50+10*((data.main[j, mmpi[i]]-mean(data.main[, mmpi[i]]))/sd(data.main[, mmpi[i]]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done in `tidyverse` where we can specify the columns of interest in `across`, loop over the columns and do the `scale/standardization`

```
library(dplyr)
data.transformed <- data.main %>%
        mutate(across(mmpi, ~ 50 + 10 * ((. - mean(.))/sd(.))))
```

As an example

```
head(mtcars) %>% 
    mutate(across(names(.)[1:3],  ~ 50 + 10 * ((. - mean(.))/sd(.))))
#       mpg      cyl     disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 52.83069 50.00000 44.23453 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 52.83069 50.00000 44.23453 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3 63.02119 34.18861 38.45053  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4 55.09525 50.00000 55.13516 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#5 39.80951 65.81139 66.48071 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#6 36.41268 50.00000 51.46454 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

---

The OP's code shows `j` for row index and `i` for column index, while the `for` loop is only looping over columns

Comment: Thank you very much! After asking question and finishing thinking I understood that every calculation of my cycle used new mean and sd, so that they were not constant for each column. I will use your method, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can accomplish this by doing:

```
data.main[, mmpi] = 50 + 10 * scale(data.main[, mmpi])
```